# Data loading problem with csv file from staging server to Database

Tags: oracle

I am trying to load data into oracle database from csv file using below statement

```
CREATE TABLE EDWOPS.SAD_344_478_Excld_list
(
  MSISDN  VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY STAGING_HW_EDWOPS
     ACCESS PARAMETERS 
       ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' optionally enclosed by 
        MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
        )
     LOCATION (STAGING_HW_EDWOPS:'DS_AT_47_20_AND_DS_AT_D_34_Nov_20_1_Exclude_list.csv') 
  )
```

Error I am getting is  given below

```
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-00554: error encountered while parsing access parameters
KUP-01005: syntax error: found "missing": expecting one of: "double-quoted-string, hexprefix, single-quoted-string"
KUP-01007: at line 2 column 9
```

My csv data format is like

```
1234567
2338848
2338888
.......
```

There are almost 6M entry in my csv file.

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing to do with the content of the file.  The key message is:

```
syntax error: found "missing":
```

Literally, when parsing the control commands it found the word "missing" where it was expecting something else.  So what was immediately preceding the word "missing"??  This:

```
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' optionally enclosed by 
        MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
```

So, what are the fields 'optionally enclosed by' ????

Comment: Thank you. I have removed 'optionally enclosed by'; then it worked

Comment: Probably a better solution would have been to complete the 'optionally enclosed by' phrase. When I pointed you to that phrase, my expectation was that it would trigger you to go back to the reference manual and look at that phrase to see how to complete it.